# Concat values returned from a function inside of a cross joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to make dates from SSRS parameters to put into a UTC conversion function
the values aren't recognized inside the concat.

i now get syntax error near 's'.

```
select concat(s.y+s.m+s.d])
from(
SELECT y.[Value] as y, m.[Value] as m, d.[Value] as d
 FROM ssrs.FnSplit(@YEAR,',') y 
cross join ssrs.FnSplit(@MONTH,',') m
cross join ssrs.FnSplit(@DAY,',') d
) s
```

code before comment

```
DECLARE @YEAR varchar(max)='2222,2111'
DECLARE @MONTH varchar(max)='1,2,3'
DECLARE @DAY varchar(max)='1,2'
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE

--SELECT @START_DATE = CAST((SELECT [Value] FROM ssrs.FnSplit(@YEAR,',') AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((SELECT [Value] FROM ssrs.FnSplit(@MONTH,',') AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
-- + '-' + CAST((SELECT [Value] FROM ssrs.FnSplit(@DAY,',') AS VARCHAR(4))

select  concat(y.[Value]+m.[Value]+d.[Value])
from (
  SELECT y.[Value], m.[Value], d.[Value]
  FROM ssrs.FnSplit(@YEAR,',') y 
  cross join ssrs.FnSplit(@MONTH,',') m
  cross join ssrs.FnSplit(@DAY,',') d
) s
```

Comment: You no longer have access to `y` where you are using `concat` you are now accessing `s`.

Comment: You have an unnecessary bracket `select concat(s.y+s.m+s.d])`.  You might also consider using different aliases for the values you're pulling to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(T1.Value, T2.Value, T3.Value) Dates
--Or CONCAT(T1.Value, '-', T2.Value, '-', T3.Value) StrDates
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YEAR, ',') T1 
     CROSS APPLY
     STRING_SPLIT(@MONTH, ',') T2
     CROSS APPLY
     STRING_SPLIT(@DAY, ',') T3;
```

Replace `STRING_SPLIT()` function with yours (`FnSplit`).